# Combinatorial Argument for the following binomial identify

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Prove the following identify using a combinatorial argument for all positive integers $n$: $${n \choose 0}-{n \choose 1}+{n \choose 2}…(-1)^n{n \choose n}$$

For odd $n$, it's simple enough, we can just use the combinatorial argument for the well known symmetry identity ${n \choose r}={n \choose n-r}$ But I can't think of what to do when $n$ is even, the alternating $±$ makes things weird.

Source of problem: Paul Zeitz's The Art and Craft of Problem Solving, $6.1.24$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : The positive terms $\binom{n}{2j}$ represent subsets of $[n]$ with an even number of elements & the negative terms $\binom{n}{2j-1}$ represent subsets of $[n]$ with an odd number of elements.

See if you can set up a $1-1$ cooresponcence between these by deleting or inserting a distinguished element.

Alternatively ... the algebraic proof ... using binomial ...

> $$(1-1)^n= {n \choose 0}-{n \choose 1}+{n \choose 2} \cdots (-1)^n{n \choose n}$$

Comment: Thank you, although I had already proved it algebraically (that was Problem 6.1.22). I will think more about how to make the bijection with your hint

Comment: Think about weather the element $1$ is in a set ... now either delete it or insert it ... this will give a $1-1$ correspondence between the sets.